# Leaflet area select in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I'm trying to use leaflet-area-select plugin in an Angular9 project, but I have a problem with it's usage.

Everytime I call `this.map.selectArea` VSCode tells me that property 'selectArea' does not exist on type 'Map'. How can I fix this?

I've installed leaflet-area-select with `npm install --save leaflet-area-select` and imported it in a component by using `import { SelectArea } from 'leaflet-area-select';`

Shall I do something else? The plugin documentation seems to be unclear about this.

Comment: You have this in html?
```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/Map.SelectArea.min.js"></script>
```

Did you instantiate your map with:
```
map = new L.Map('map');
```

Could be that your app is not using the correct definition of map.. look at your imports if there is another map (from RxJs for example)

Comment: I checked, there's no another map object. Adding a <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/Map.SelectArea.min.js"></script> tag into index.html didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and managed to fix it by changing the import reference from `import { SelectArea } from 'leaflet-area-select';` to `import 'leaflet-area-select';`